# JSF app error in javascript - "mojarra" undefined - when deployed on WebLogic

Tags: jsf, weblogic11g

My application has been developed and deploys/executes without problems under the integrated WebLogic Server in Eclipse. Now that I'm deploying to a shared server, using the same version of WLS (10.3.6.0), I'm running into issues.

My form has a hidden button that allows Javascript to invoke a method in my backing bean. When the form is created in the browser (IE 9), the onclick event is

```
    mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','@form','@none');return false
```

When the javascript reaches the point where it "clicks" the button, I'm getting an error that mojarra is undefined.

I've had to do all kinds of stuff differently when deploying on a shared WLS, but now I'm wondering what is causing this and does anyone have a solution?

Comment: do you use <h:head></h:head> tags in your page?

Comment: `mojarra` is defined in `jsf.js` file. This file is supposed to be auto-included if you have a `<h:head>`. Just check the generated HTML output and the HTTP traffic if it's properly added by JSF and downloaded by webbrowser and served by webserver.

Comment: Yes, there are the correct head tags - that was the first thing that I checked when I googled on this last week. It is generating the include for jsf.js but the src ref may be the issue. For some reason, the WLS that I'm deploying on does not seem to recognize the /faces as an actual directory, and the include is src="/kwik_gatora/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js". I've already had to change other ones to my own javascript files from src="js/KWIKfunctions.js" to src="../js/KWIKfunctions.js" for this WLS. Does anyone know if there is a setting in WLS 10.3.6.0 that could overcome this issue?